# Declare List<List<string>> with auto name and number in C#

Tags: c#

I have a `Dictionary<string,string>`. I want to declare `List<List<string>>` with name and number depend on key of Dictionary.

```
var assetTypeName = assetType.Select(type => type.Name).ToList();
List<List<string>> exGeneral;
List<List<string>> exTablet;
List<List<string>> exLaptop;
List<List<string>> exPhone;
```

I want to create `List<List<string>>` like `List<List<string>> exGeneral`, with name and number depend on assetTypeName.

Comment: not sure about the question but by assumption Dictionary<string, List<string>> dic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do? Can you write some code that works like you want, even if it is wrong? Right now its difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Why not just use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` instead of nested lists and multiple collections you need to synchronize? Lists don't have keys like Dictionary does.

Comment: @RonBeyer, thanks for help! I fixed.

Comment: Still your question is not clear? What you'll store in `List<List<string>>`? What is number in *"with name and number depend on key of Dictionary"*? Add some sample data and your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int,string>();

dic.Add(1,"one");
dic.Add(2,"two");

var keys = dic.Keys.ToList();
var values = dic.Values.ToList();
```